# System collapse

Tags: 16.04

Everything is starting with disconnecting from the internet and then the whole system starts to behaves weird - applications are not responding, the system is freezing and I can't even restart a computer.

I used Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity and it happened every day, so I have switched to Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome, hoping that it may solve the problem. Today I have finally looked into logs, but it is useless to me as a Linux noobie.

Please, could you explain me why it is happening and how could I fix it? See an image for further details. Everything starts at 20:05.

[image: Log]

Comment: 20:05 isn't visible, and we can't scroll down in a screenshot :)

Comment: @NickWeinberg What do you mean? It is a log at 20:05 starting with a message "INFO: task kworker .....". Since then Ubuntu stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded my kernel from 4.4.0 to 4.7.0 (currently the last stable one) and seems that the problem disappears.